# Simple command line storage tools for Azure Storage (like s3cmd, sdbShell)?

Tags: amazon-s3, azure, simpledb

I'm currently backing up/migrating Amazon S3 and SimpleDB data from AWS to my on premise systems using [sdbShell](http://code.google.com/p/typica/) and [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3tools). Works great.

Now we're putting an app up on Microsoft Azure and I want to extend my reach to those. Are there any utilities like this for Azure?  Ideally they'd work from my existing UNIX host but I could be talked out of that, but they need to be command line and not GUI doodads, I run these nightly and tied to some system automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [project](http://code.google.com/p/azure-command-line-console/) might fit your bill. And, it might be cross-platform too, since it's browser-based.

Comment: Uh, this looks handy but not sure it's relevant - it's a command line version of "RDP to an Azure instance" right? I am trying to back up Azure storage.

Comment: It does work a bit like sdbShell as it does let you run pretty much any command remotely on your Azure instances. It doesn't cover much of storage management though. If you are comfortable with PowerShell, then take a look at this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575225/where-can-i-find-azure-storage-cmdlets-for-powershell) or [this](http://azure-tools.com/2011/03/azure-management-cmdlets/#more-64). If you want to run these under Unix/Linux, you'd have to use [Posh](http://posh.sf.net) with Mono. The nice part about these is that they are completely scriptable.

Comment: Thanks, I think we'll go with a combo of buying the Cerebrata cmdlets and custom development.  The world could use "rsync that works with all the different cloud providers' storage."